# Анимация масштабирования

Tags: c#, wpf, анимация, масштабирование

Подскажите пожалуйста пример кода, чтобы при нажатии кнопки изменялся горизонтальный размер, например листбокса listbox1 от 0 до 1, то есть чтобы он как бы появлялся, и нужно именно с анимацией на пару секунд.

Comment: что такое "горизонтальный масштаб"?

Comment: @Ev_Hyper  имеется ввиду горизонтальный размер. Просто сам размер задается фиксировано, а для анимации применяется коэффициент масштабирования. Но формулировку в вопросе пожалуй стоит поправить